# Dialog Flow ( Api.ai ) Conversation in chatbot

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es, api-ai

I am having a welcome intent and it allows user to select three different actions. Ex: Welcome! you can print your firstname, you can print your lastname or you can print your zipcode. If User select or enter last name then it should call the last name intent. So we are providing multiple options at welcome intent itself and user can choose any one of them.
Based on the action selected by user, the conversation should occur.
Please help me how to achieve this.﻿

Answer (score 1):

You are giving the user the option of proceeding by providing their first name, their last name or their zip code.

To capture their response, you will need to create three intents:

- Capture First Name
- Capture Last Name
- Capture Zip Code

For each intent, you would provide a series of example phrases showing how the user might express each thing. For example, "Capture First Name" might contain examples like:

- "My first name is Dan"
- "Dan"
- "Dan is my first name"

I'd recommend providing around 10 examples for each intent.

Dialogflow provides a [system entity for zip codes](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/system-entities#geography), so it will be able to automatically extract the zip code from the "Capture Zip Code" intent.

However, to make the first and last name intents work, you'll need to create entities to represent the first and last names of all your users. Assuming you know these values ahead of time, you should first create each entity and then write a script to populate it from your datastore using the Dialogflow API's [/entities endpoint](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/entities#put_entities).

Once you've created and populated these entities, add some examples that make use of them to your intents. Ensure that you highlight and annotate any entity values that are not automatically identified.

When your intents are complete, you can use Dialogflow's [fulfillment](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment) to send the information they capture to your back-end.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when the welcome intent triggered it will send a request to your backend through webhook,from backend you can send responses as templates or buttons and user can choose one of them ,if you are using backend here

Else in welcome intent response,use a response like you can print firstname ,you can print second name and configure intents for those and use contexts for proper flow.

In the second intent,keep one entity containing some values for first name and use a output context like frstname_output_context

In the another intent,keep one entity containing some values for last name as entity and use a output context like lsttname_output_context

Hope it clarifies using webhook and without webhook.